# Asus laptop doesn't wake-up from sleep. It's restarting

Tags: laptop, sleep, asus-laptop

Since short time, I have a sleep issue with my Asus laptop F751LAV. When I put the laptop in sleep mode (close led, LED light shows sleep mode), and when I open the laptop, it restarts instead of wake-up from sleep mode. But hibernate works.

So I check the laptop using the latest ACPI drivers and latest BIOS firmware. All true and not the solution. Then a clean install of Windows 10 doesn't wake-up the laptop correctly.

With 'powercfg /a' the Standy S3 is available.

Also disable fast boot doesn't help.

The eventviewer reports not good reason: only that Windows was not correctly shutdown etc.

OS is Windows 10 Home.

Sometime a good idea to check or to do?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The only solution I found which really works is to install the same BIOS version you already have installed again. So install the same version on top of the version you have installed. It apparently causes some refreshed setting and the problem is solved. Tricky might be to find the tool to install the BIOS. Most tools don't allow to install the same version of a BIOS. I know there is an Asus BIOS tool, but you need to search for which one exactly. I didn't keep the link unfortunately.

Comment: Echoing this answer. It seems counterintuitive, and you'd think such problems would be corrected at the factory or fixed by checksumming, but I have had random "strange" issues like this corrected by a bios reflash.